Who does this refer to " no bearer of burdens"
In Quran it says " no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another".
Who is " bearer of burdens" adressing to?
Is it only humans or other creatures too?

In this world if one person has some problems, others can help to reduce his problems by will of Allah. But in the hereafter no one can help each other and reduce the burden of others. This is what is meant by no one can bear the burden of others.

Yes but, "bearer of burdens" is who?
